# unable to use `page.select` in render update inside controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rjs

In my controller I am using render update,but I want to update only if div element if present.
In order to check if div element is present, I am using `page.select` but its not responding with anything,neither error or output,here is my code

```
def post_update
render :update do |page|
   page.replace_html('div_id':partial=>'my_partial') unless page.select("#div_id").blank?
  end
end
```

is there anything I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use ruby conditionals like that in rjs: that "unless" and `page.select` are executed on your server and have no idea what the contents of the DOM are.

I once wrote a [blog post](http://www.spacevatican.org/2008/5/26/conditional-rjs-explained) with a few ways of dealing with this. The short version is probably "generate Javascript fragments with your conditions". These days I'd stay away from rjs: render json or HTML and  have some JavaScript on your page that knows what to do with it.

Comment: @Frederick_Cheung so there is no way I can access javascript element from my controller ?

Comment: no. The information just isn't there (unless of course you start passing extra parameters with your request with the information you need)